# convert a class object into another class object and then combine

Tags: c#, linq

Say that I have two models/classes.

```
public class Male
{
    public int RunNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime thing {get ; set;}
}

public class Female
{
    public int StopNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime? thing {get;set;}
}
```

I want a `List<People>` by combining `List<Male>` and `List<Female>`.  Every time I look at LINQ, my brain doesn't cooperate with me.  I think it's concat I'm after.

Comment: In your example neither `Male` nor `Female` objects are `People`, so you can't create a `List<People>` from males and females.

Comment: If you have a way to convert `List<Male>` and `List<Female>` each to `List<Person>` then yes a `Concat` will "combine" the two resulting lists into a new one.

Comment: What have you tired so far?!

Comment: Create a class 'People' and let 'Male' and 'Female' inherit from it. Then you'll be able to create a 'List<People>'

Comment: You cannot combine two strongly typed classes into one strongly type list. You'll get an syntax and explicit error. However, you can have an `interface` or an `abstract` class that your Male or Female object can inherit. So for instance `var list = new List<Person>();`. `Person` being the interface or base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to get too fancy, and there is a reason that Male & Female have different members (no pun intended) and do not inherit a common parent, create a data transfer object and use Select to map into it.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int StopNumber { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public DateTime? thing { get; set; }
        public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Person> Join(List<Male> males, List<Female> females)
    {
        return
            males.Select(
                n => new Person() {
                    IsMale = true, 
                    Notes = n.Notes, 
                    StopNumber = n.RunNumber, 
                    thing = n.thing} 
            ).Concat(
                     females.Select(
                         m => new Person() {
                                IsMale = false,
                                Notes = m.Notes, 
                                StopNumber = m.StopNumber, 
                                thing = m.thing})
                ).ToList();
    }
```

However -- if they can inherit a common Person base class and have common member names, it will make your life far easier.